# Insert new entity to context with identity primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to insert a new record into my SQL table.  I tried:

```
        public void CreateComment(int questionId, string comment)
        {
            QuestionComment questionComment = context.TableName.Create();//1*
            questionComment.propertyThatIsNotAConstraint= questionId;
            questionComment.body = comment;
            context.QuestionComments.Add(questionComment);
            context.SaveChanges();//ERROR...
        }
```

1* I'm surprised to see intellisense tell me:  **"Note that the new entity is not added or attached to the set"**

Error Reads:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TableName'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.TableName'. The duplicate key value is
>   (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

The problem is that `questionComment` has its PK: `questionComment.Id` defaulted to `0`.  It needs to be the next available Identity or otherwise not populated and do a "normal" identity insert.

How does entity framework expect me to handle this scenerio?

As Requested:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace Feedback.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class QuestionComment
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int questionId { get; set; }
            public string body { get; set; }
            public int commentIndex { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After calling `SaveChanges()`, `newCommentObject.questionId` will contain the newly generated key by the database.

Comment: @haim770 - I updated the question with the exact error I am receiving and the location of the error.  If there's some mechanism or ordering that can resolve this please post an answer.

Comment: I typically do something like this: my `IDENTITY` in the database goes from 1 on up; my new entities in C# get "fake" PK values from -1 downwards - those will then be replaced when the actual insert into the table happens (but having separate, distinct "fake" PK values make sure you can work with the entities just fine, and even reference them from other entities!)

Comment: What type of mapping are you using? Please post the mapping code as well as the `QuestionComment` class.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve by creating the entity using `context.TableName.Create()`? it is not clear what type of entity you're actually adding, is it `TableName` or `QuestionComment`?

Comment: @marc_s - Are you saying that entity framework does not support any concept of "identity insert on" per-se?  I have to obtain the next key manually?

Comment: Quoting from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx: The Entity Framework convention for primary keys is:

1.       Your class defines a property whose name is “ID” or “Id”

2.       or a class name followed by “ID” or “Id”.
----
I would guess your `id` field is not mapped as the primary-key at all.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I fixed it by:

1. Go to SQL and make sure to the Table has the "Identity Specification" > Is Identity > set to Yes.  Then update the *.edmx file if you had to make a DB change.
2. Check the *.edmx > Entity properties > StoreGeneratedPattern for the identity to ensure that it is set to **Identity**

[image]

Comment: Dude, I was tearing my hair out with this same error, didn't realise I'd not created an identity column. Thanks! (yeah, I know, "thanks" comments are frowned upon)

Comment: Updating the .edmx file didn't work for me. I had to delete the table from the .edmx and re-add it.

Answer (score 4):

EF documentation states that the database generates a value when a row is inserted for columns configured with `propConfig.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829109(v=vs.103).aspx

In other words.  EF won't care what value `newCommentObject.Id` is when inserting into the database.  Instead, it'll allow the database to generate the next identity value.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this to my situation.  I am not familiar with this property.  Can you show how this applies to my question?  In other words, code that demonstrates how to fix the error.

Comment: Presumably you set up your QuestionComments table.  If you used EF's fluent api it may look like `modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionComments>()
.HasKey(c => /* */);`.  You could mofify the setup to be `modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionComments>()
.HasKey(c => c.Id /* If Id is the primary key for the table */);` or  to `modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionComments>()
.HasKey(c => /* */).Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`

I'd probably recommend making Id on QuestionComments the primary key of the table because it sounds like it is.